# Storing pointer to method parameter for later reuse

Tags: c#, pointers, lambda

Similar to how lambda expressions with free variables work I would like to implement my own closure class that captures some method parameter.

```
public class Closure<TObject, TVariable>
{
    public TVariable Variable { get; set; }
    public Func<TObject, bool> Predicate { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have some class that works with `DateTime` instances. One of the methods that should use this closure class is this:

```
// Original Version
public IEnumerable<Item> GetDayData(DateTime day)
{
    this.items.Where(i => i.IsValidForDay(day));
}
```

I would like to convert it to use `Closure` class. The problem is that I would like to reuse (performance reasons) my `Closure` class instance:

```
private Closure<Item, DateTime> closure = null;
public IEnumerable<Item> GetDayData(DateTime day)
{
    if (closure == null)
    {
        this.closure = new Closure<Item, DateTime>() {
            Variable = reference of "day" param, <=== HOW ????????
            Predicate = i => i.IsValidForDay(this.closure.Variable)
        }
    }
    this.items.Where(this.closure.Predicate);
}
```

In order for me to reuse the same `Closure` instance I would have to not store the value of the parameter (into closure's `Variable` field) but rather method parameter's reference pointer. So the next time this method gets called closure's `Variable` would actually point to the correct value to be used.

**How am I supposed to do this**?

A similar thing is done when compiler generates classes that capture lambda expression free variables. I've been looking at decompiled code (using Reflector), but I don't seem to understand how that's done...

Comment: Probably need to write a post compiler doing something similar to the actual compiler.

Comment: @Femaref: What do you mean by that? Compiler is obviously able to do something like it because lambda expressions work and free variables are captured using generated classes. And these classes are reused without re-setting their variable on each method call.

Comment: Hint: Closures are the poor man's classes, classes are the poor man's closures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is slightly wrong (also this probably wont work, but the semantics/intent is correct):

```
private Closure<Item, DateTime> closure = null;
public IEnumerable<Item> GetDayData(DateTime day)
{
    if (closure == null)
    {
        this.closure = new Closure<Item, DateTime>() {
            Predicate = i => i.IsValidForDay(this.closure.Variable)
        }
    }
    // assign here, else you only capture it the first time
    closure.Variable = day;
    this.items.Where(this.closure.Predicate);
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the *workaround*. But if you look at decompiled lambda expression it doesn't work this way. And this introduces a slew of developer mistakes not setting the value... This actually makes it worse. Hence I'd like to store parameter reference instead of its value...

Comment: I edited my question to correct the **obvious** mistake that was pointed out and you provided the workaround I was aware of even before but **would like to avoid**.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean. Let me reread the question :)

Comment: So, how do you plan to get the value of `day` on the second invocation of `GetDayData`? Or do you want to only capture the initial value and reuse that, like currying?

Comment: I want to get the value of `day` by storing its reference pointer instead of its value. This way I can get to the actual value every time `GetDayData` gets called. That must be some trickery behind compiler generated class because if you compile the *Original version* method (look up in question I've marked it with a comment) you can see that closure object gets reused but without re-setting captured variable's value... So I suppose it should be possible to store reference pointer to method parameter instead of its value. Even if using `unsafe` blocks in Closure class. I don't mind...

Comment: OK, I think I understand. First problem: This will be nigh impossible on a valuetype as there is no reference (not a reference type). As for a reference type, the address might change on every invocation. Even then I cannot think of a way to achieve this. Perhaps try a prototype in C, if you can get it working there, you may be able to get something right with `unsafe`.

Comment: That makes sense yes. Value type parameters are passed to method via stack right? Hence they have no formal *pointer* to them... Ok. What I want is impossible. But... Can you explain how compiler does it then? Because there's no captured variable assignment going on (as you did it in your example) but it still works as expected. As if value got automatically updated, but there's no code that proves it.

Comment: oh an one more thing... Passing value types is possible using reference hence `ref` keyword... Those parameters are passed to method as references because they change original variable's value. So if I could say `public ref TVariable Variable { get; set; }` would be exactly what I want.:)

Comment: In the example, a reference to the closure instance is captured (which is a reference type, or maybe `this` gets captured, never sure of that). It does not matter what you access from that captured reference. I am not sure what you mean by "there's no captured variable assignment going" as I do `closure.Variable = day;` which mutates a field/property on the captured value before the subsequent invocation of `Predicate`.

Comment: Also, if you reassign the captured reference's variable, the closure will still refer to the original value. Eg `closure = somethingelse;` But as I said in my other comment, I am not always sure about how capturing works with instance members. It is generally good practice to only capture values that are NOT accessible in any other way, generally locals.

Comment: I know you're re-assigning the value to closure field/property... But somehow I think (but can't find the actual compiled source) that variable capturing done by the compiler doesn't do it (I may of course be wrong since I can't find if anywhere). You haven't commented on `ref` parameters and capturing their references. BTW: using fields in closure classes instead of properties is also faster. About 7% faster... Which is rather significant... https://gist.github.com/1403144

Comment: I tend to use fields of properties in the internal details too. Some say bad style, but I say more functionality and speed (you can `ref` a field, but not a property). I can't see any way that `ref` can work (as you pointed out). You could try `unsafe` here, but again, the address is not reliable over multiple invocations.

Answer (score 0):

You can have references to local variables, but those are managed references and can't be stored in fields.

The closures the compiler generates work by replacing local variables with fields. So it looks like a local variable at the C# level, but like a field at the CLR level.

But in your case I see no reason why you'd want to capture local variables by reference. So it should be possible to do something like you want:

```
public class Closure<TObject, TVariable>
{
    public TVariable Variable { get; set; }
    public Func<TVariable, TObject, bool> OpenPredicate { get; set; }

    public bool ClosedPredicate(TObject o)
    {
      return OpenPredicate(this, o);
    }
}

private Closure<Item, DateTime> closure = null;
public IEnumerable<Item> GetDayData(DateTime day)
{
    if (closure == null)
    {
        this.closure = new Closure<Item, DateTime>() {
            OpenPredicate = (closure, i) => i.IsValidForDay(closure.Variable)
        }
    }
    closure.Variable=day;
    this.items.Where(this.closure.ClosedPredicate);
}
```

But I think this code is a bad idea. If performance is so critical, throw out the LINQ, and do it yourself. The delegate invocation overhead is much bigger that the cost of creating an object or two. In my experience LINQ is typically slower by a factor of 2-3 compared to hand written code.

Also this code creates several more objects:

- `items.GetEumerator()` returns one, unless it's a value type or resures the Enumerable.
- `Where` returns a new `IEnumerable`
- Enumerating the result of your function creates another Enumerator.
- You get a new delegate instance each time

Thus I think tying to reuse the closure for performance reason is useless.

Comment: Slower? Not really. Using my custom Closure class that uses fields internally is 7% faster than manual `foreach` statement or any other way. https://gist.github.com/1403144 and LINQ (or better said lambda because I suppose you meant that) is fast as long as properly written. But otherwise it can be slower... even 10x. In my example predicate builder shows this same factor. almost 10x slower.

Comment: And btw. The code you presented here is practically the same as @leppie provided... Although your doesn't compile because I don't see where you use Open/Close predicates?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik I don't see any manual implementation in there.

Comment: This code of yours can't work because if you set your private variable `closer` to be of type `Closure<Item, DateTime>` then `closure.OpenPredicate` property would be of type `Func<DateTime, Item, bool>`. It can't be right with either your property definition or your code inside the class.

Comment: Your code approach is otherwise very interesting... But if I changed type of your `OpenPredicate` (which is probably an unintended mistake) your code does work but very slow. I'm not exactly sure why that is, but you can check for yourself: https://gist.github.com/1403144 (check the `CustomClosureLambdaRangeLookup` class that implements your code). Maybe you can provide some additional changes, to speed it up a bit.

Answer (score -1):

```
        List<PicInfo> pi = new List<PicInfo>();
        pi.Add(new PicInfo() { fileName = "a" });
        pi.Add(new PicInfo() { fileName = "a" });
        pi.Add(new PicInfo() { fileName = "b" });
        pi.Add(new PicInfo() { fileName = "b" });
        pi.Add(new PicInfo() { fileName = "a" });            

        string a = "a";
        Closure<PicInfo, string> cl = null;
        cl = new Closure<PicInfo, string>() { 
                  Variable = a, 
                  predicate = (i => i.fileName == cl.Variable.ToString()) 
        };
        MessageBox.Show(pi.Where(cl.predicate).Count().ToString()); // shows 3
        // Change variable value here
        string b = "b";
        cl.Variable = b;
        MessageBox.Show(pi.Where(cl.predicate).Count().ToString()); // Shows 2
```

@Robert Koritnik, this is working for me, `with your existing class`. If you want to just change the variable with existing instance, you can set to Variable property

Comment: This can't even be considered the same answer any more, because there's hardly any word from the original answer here. And what you've edited and changed/added is basically the very same thing that the other two posters did. Thanks anyway. Appreciate your effort. I believe you've learned something new yourself as well. :) *Ps. I'm removing all my comments due to completely changed answer; they don't apply any more...*

Comment: But the original question was actually asking whether it's possible to re-use a `Closure` class instance without setting its `Variable` property.